# how to display two data outputs in an interactive html report using shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have two data outputs as below.I want to display them in an interactive html report using shiny.How can i do that as i am new to shiny.

```
max_usage_hours_per_region<-setNames(aggregate(df3_machine_region$sum_as_hours~df3_machine_region$Region,df3_machine_region,max),c("Region","Sum_as_Hours"))

Region Sum_as_Hours
1 Africa 1156.0833
2 Americas 740.1667
3 APAC 740.2833
4 Europe 1895.2000
5 PDO 1053.3500
6 UK 0.0000

mean_usage_hours_per_region<-setNames(aggregate(df3_machine_region$sum_as_hours~df3_machine_region$Region,df3_machine_region,mean),c("Region","Sum_as_Hours"))
Region Sum_as_Hours
1 Africa 1.7046559
2 Americas 0.7578695
3 APAC 7.5799541
4 Europe 4.9651339
5 PDO 8.2637964
6 UK 0.0000000
```

I want to have region as the input bar/field wrt both the above functions for which user can select options for which the data will be accordingly displayed.

Comment: Have a look at https://mastering-shiny.org. You'll need functions like `selectInput` and `renderTable`

Comment: @starja Thanks for the info.Well i tried using one of the code in rshiny but the table is not rendering.Please see the example below.

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput("Region","Select Region",max_usage_hours_per_region$Region,selected = TRUE)
)
server <- function(input, output) {
output$table <- renderTable(
max_usage_hours_per_region[,input$Region])
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)